# How to check data type image in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I need a help to get conditional data from mysql (WordPress database). Please see the screenshot

[image]

how can I get row where post_mine_type image/jpg or image/png .....
Is it possible to Rtrim in mysql? so I can match only image

Like this one

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_type = 'attachment'and  post_mine_type = 'image' limit 1 offset 0", OBJECT );
```

Thanks all

Comment: You could use: `WHERE post_mime_type LIKE 'image/%' `

Comment: This one worked ! Thanks you very much snwflk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like).

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_type = 'attachment'and post_mine_type LIKE 'image/%' limit 1 offset 0", OBJECT );
```